# Problem connecting to db after securing phpmyadmin with htaccess & htpasswd

Tags: change-password, database-connection

I recently having an idea of securing my phpmyadmin portal, So i added htaccess and htpasswd to add another layer of protection 
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]

And I realized that my web application is now no longer able to access the connection to my db , since I have added another layer of auth type. I notice that env.php are responsible for taking notes on credential to log in my web app to my db.

So what command line should I add into env.php to enable this authenticate the new layer I had created (.htaccess " auth type: basic ")

Btw my issue originated from (SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied)

> {"0":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied","1":"#1
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:406]\n#2
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect() called at
>   [vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:460

Comment: Please share the content of env.php?

Comment: updated ,check above

Comment: If you are using **`localhost`** in the host value, then there should not be such a problem. Please reconfirm.

Comment: what is the issue that might trigger SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied?